# how many jvm processes are used for a spark worker?

Tags: apache-spark

Each spark executor runs in its own JVM process which means that on each worker (slave) there will be multiple JVMs running. Is it safe to say that each worker runs as many JVMs as there are executors assigned to that machine + at least one more JVM (because spark needs at least one more JVM for BlockManager on each worker). In other words, is the BlockManager on each worker run on a different JVM process ?

Answer (score -1):

Which cluster manager you are using ?

Spark uses cluster managers like K8s/ Mesos/ Yarn for resource allocation. Where the JVM is to run will be decided by the cluster manager. Spark as client request for resources from these cluster managers.

Comment: I'm using YARN at the moment, but does it matter ? it shouldn't

Comment: The answer is its one jvm per executor , and 1 task per core of the executor.

Comment: What about the other tools needed ?  ... like the ones I mentioned (BlockManager). If the executors run in their own JVM then at least one other JVM is required for BlockManager & stuff.

Comment: would you mind posting an answer ? .... Your answer is correct I don't want to answer it myself  ..